# How to trim down the total ammount of keyframes in a animation

Tags: animation, keyframes, motion-capture

Hey guys I'm currently working on a motion capture project using the rokoko studio. At the moment studio exports animations at 100 fps and can't be changed. This leaves a huge number of keyframes in the animation for me to have to go through and clean up. I was wanting to find out if there was a way to pack down the sheer number of keyframes to something more manageable like 30fps.

Comment: Have you tried "Simplify Curve" operator? With cursor in Curve Editor hit search. If not there probably needed activate an add-on in Preferences. I m on tablet can't ensure now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youn go to pose mode, menu pose, animation, bake action, and set the frame step to three, reducing at one third the number of keyframes.

[image]

Comment: Yeah this has worked supper well for me. Thank you so much for this.